# Sqlite embedded prebuilds for node project?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

there is sqlite3 npm package as embedded database for nodeJs

As it's embedded I'm trying to bundle it using webpack+babel

cause I want my bundle to be independent from node_modules folder at all

currently bundling sqlite is possible using only sqlite3-loader but that doesn't support cross-compilation (it includes only current platform .node file)

how to support multiple node files?